# Prevent java from producing incorrect result

Tags: java, math

```
System.out.println((int) (368*Math.pow(2416,2)+100*2416+100));
```

does not produce the same output as a calculator would or python, what might be the reason for this?

Comment: What are you getting? What are you expecting? Why are you casting to an integer?

Comment: what is the result you are having, and what is the result you expect ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: One thing new programmers stumble over is how incredibly dumb computers are.  They always do exactly what we tell them, even if that doesn't make *any* sense.  Here, we've asked the computer to perform a calculation that we (should) know is going to be pretty large, and store the result in a data structure that can't hold the result.  So, you get a broken answer.  Contrary to intuitive sense, computers aren't good at math; programmers are.  So you, the programmer, are responsible for making sure the computer can perform the requested calculation (which it cant)

Comment: It's not the duplicate that I linked initially. But following Gus' suggestion: Look at Integer.MAX_VALUE and compare your result (before casting to int) and also cast to long. Check Long.MAX_VALUE as well. Most likely a duplicate to a different question - would have been obvious if you'd given the values from the start.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the expression is larger than the range of java int.
Since you are casting to int (java primitive type) which ranges from -2,147,483,648 (-2^31) to 2,147,483,647 ((2^31)-1), the code produces 2147483647(upper limit of java int data-type) as the output whereas the calculator will give correct result.